# Корни аббревиатурных образований и сокращений

Tags: морфология

По горячим следам недавнего вопроса.

Каковы крони слов типа колхоз, худрук, дот, вуз?
Если тут выделять два и более корней, то зачем? И считать ли такие корни родственными исходным, неусеченным корням?

Нужны ссылки на авторитетные мнения. Хотя бы на словари.

ЗЫ нашел [Тихонова](http://slovari.yandex.ru/~%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C/~%D0%92%D1%83/) на Яндексе. 
Там действительно в слове "вуз" - три корня. Но он ничего не объясняет. Является ли "в" самостоятельным корнем или вариантом корня "выс(ший)"?

Comment: вы с таким пренебрежительным превосходством отвечаете, что скоро отвечать будут только абсолютные новички

Comment: Лорана, здесь я *спрашиваю*.
А отвечаете Вы. И явно не по делу.  

ЗЫ Всё личное кидайте сюда: bethemothus.(at).mail.ru.

Comment: Ну и что, что спрашиваете? Можно подумать, мы Вас не знаем. Видимо, у некоторых Вы, к сожалению, отбили охоту общаться... Немного последить за корректностью не помешает - не все такие толстокожие, как я, например (мне можете грубить, если припрет!)

Comment: DocentI, я с величашим удовеольствием отобью охоту общаться со мной, кто считает переход на личности приемлемой формой общения на форуме, посвященом совсем другим проблемам. Вопрос только - как это сделать.  
Точно ток же я не намерен менять стиль общения с теми, кто пишет что-то ради того, чтобы что-то написать.  
Замечания принимаю с благодарностью - но только конкретные. А всё, что касается моей личности желательно в личку. 
DIXI

Comment: Подсказать, как отбить охоту общаться? Не подскажу, так как такой образ действий вообще не приходит мне в голову. Я в такой ситуации просто промолчу.

Comment: О то ж.(С)
~~~~   
Ладно, поскольку этот театр абсурда явно затягивается, могу предложить только последовать словам Леопольда.   
"Реябта, давайте жить дружно". Разумеется, это не значит, что считаю себя в чем-то провинившимся.

Comment: Переоткрываю. г-н Марк Из наверняка захочет объяснить объяснить свой минус в давно закрытом вопросе, в котором ни слова по делу не было сказано.  
ЗЫ Долго искали, г-н историк?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Выполняя морфемный анализ слова,  нужно помнить о следующих моментах.

Первое,  должен быть синхронический подход.
Второе, учитываем значение слова.

Третье, нужно помнить, что при образовании слова могут происходить разные процессы: чередование, сокращение, опрощение и др.

*Иняз* – это иностранный язык. Это всем настолько понятно, что до сих пор  большинством словарей слитное написание не фиксируется! И какие есть варианты ?  Новый корень *иняз*? То же с *вуз*, *худрук…*  Эти слова членятся (возможно, пока), у них не один корень, но корни эти сокращенные.

Но вот в словах типа *самбо* (самооборона без оружия), *Вилора* , возможно, и *дот*    - я бы выделила только один корень , как и в слове *сегодня* .  Без специального знания эти слова не осознаются как членимые.

Из статей почитайте уважаемого  Вами Лопатина "О некоторых принципах морфемного анализа слов" (статья в Известиях Академии наук за 1963 год). [здесь](http://feb-web.ru/feb/izvest/1963/03/633-190.htm)

Comment: Боюсь, что для меня вуз воспринимается как нечленимое, хотя, конечно, я знаю его происхождение.

Comment: Ларf, спасибо. Я правильно понимаю, что Вы (или те авторитеты, которым Вы следутете) во главу угла ставят распознавание слова носителями? Для меня понимание слова "самбо", "дот" не требует специальных знаний. Да и в обычной литератере встречается без всяких оговорок. Но не в этом дело... Непонятно, как онтноситься к таким "корням". Скажем, в словах вуз и учпедгиз "у" и "уч" - это один корень или разные?  Вот где собаке-то зарыться... А декларировать можно что угодно...

Варианты, естественно, - новый нечленимый корень. Как решили с "Беларусью".  

>уважаемого Вами Лопатина   

Однако...

Comment: А там точно что-то есть по теме? На какой странице, если не секрет? Или это тоже из серии "ищите - да обрящете"?

Comment: Статья посвящена принципам морфемного анализа. Поэтому выбирать для Вас именно про сложные слова не стала. Кажется, где-то во второй половине...

Comment: Спасибо, принципов кушано достаточно. Конкретно по теме ничего нет.

>Присоединяюсь ко всем замечаниям, сказанным выше, и не понимаю, почему Вы грубите публично, а замечания просите посылать вам на почту?

Потому что переходить на личностим в теме мне воспитание не позволяет. В отличие от авторов голословных наездов. Больше эту тему здесь не обсуждаю.